# Triangle arrows with text above

Tags: color, arrows, text

I would like to use black and white triangle arrows with text above like these:

[image: arrows]

I guess that I have to combine `\longrightarrow` `\xrightarrow{W}` and `\rightarrowtriangle` but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Messing around with the code found in `mathtools`, which defines several types of extensible arrows on, I got the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\makeatletter
\providecommand*\xrightarrowtriangle[2][]{%
  \ext@arrow 0055{\arrowfill@\relbar\relbar\rightarrowtriangle}{#1}{#2}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \[
        x \rightarrowtriangle y, \qquad x \xrightarrowtriangle{i} y
    \]

    Some unknown text les transitions synchrones par xyzqwert

    \[
        x \rightarrow y, \qquad x \xrightarrow{W} y
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

**EDIT**: To get filled arrows with the same shape as the empty ones, I used the `\rhd` (▷) and `\RHD` (▶) commands from `wasysym`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\providecommand\rightarrowRHD{\relbar\joinrel\mathrel\RHD}
\providecommand\rightarrowrhd{\relbar\joinrel\mathrel\rhd}
\providecommand\longrightarrowRHD{\relbar\joinrel\relbar\joinrel\mathrel\RHD}
\providecommand\longrightarrowrhd{\relbar\joinrel\relbar\joinrel\mathrel\rhd}

\makeatletter
\providecommand*\xrightarrowRHD[2][]{\ext@arrow 0055{\arrowfill@\relbar\relbar\longrightarrowRHD}{#1}{#2}}
\providecommand*\xrightarrowrhd[2][]{\ext@arrow 0055{\arrowfill@\relbar\relbar\longrightarrowrhd}{#1}{#2}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{lcccc}
        \toprule
        type               &   displaystyle                            &   textstyle                            &   scriptstyle                            \\
        \midrule
        filled short       & $\displaystyle a \rightarrowRHD        b$ & $\textstyle a \rightarrowRHD        b$ & $\scriptstyle a \rightarrowRHD        b$ \\
        empty  short       & $\displaystyle a \rightarrowrhd        b$ & $\textstyle a \rightarrowrhd        b$ & $\scriptstyle a \rightarrowrhd        b$ \\
        filled long        & $\displaystyle a \longrightarrowRHD    b$ & $\textstyle a \longrightarrowRHD    b$ & $\scriptstyle a \longrightarrowRHD    b$ \\
        empty  long        & $\displaystyle a \longrightarrowrhd    b$ & $\textstyle a \longrightarrowrhd    b$ & $\scriptstyle a \longrightarrowrhd    b$ \\
        filled superscript & $\displaystyle a \xrightarrowRHD{c}    b$ & $\textstyle a \xrightarrowRHD{c}    b$ & $\scriptstyle a \xrightarrowRHD{c}    b$ \\
        empty  superscript & $\displaystyle a \xrightarrowrhd{c}    b$ & $\textstyle a \xrightarrowrhd{c}    b$ & $\scriptstyle a \xrightarrowrhd{c}    b$ \\
        filled sup+super   & $\displaystyle a \xrightarrowRHD[d]{c} b$ & $\textstyle a \xrightarrowRHD[d]{c} b$ & $\scriptstyle a \xrightarrowRHD[d]{c} b$ \\
        empty  sub+super   & $\displaystyle a \xrightarrowrhd[d]{c} b$ & $\textstyle a \xrightarrowrhd[d]{c} b$ & $\scriptstyle a \xrightarrowrhd[d]{c} b$ \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: new output]

They have the same behavior as `\longrightarrow` and friends in that they don't scale as much (at all?) as the regular arrows.

Comment: I like the fact that you do not use TikZ here.

Comment: I find it necessary to re-scale it:  `\providecommand\Heytingarrow{\relbar\joinrel\mathrel{\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{0.75}{$\rhd$}}}}}`

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is an overkill solution with Ti*k*Z but it is handy to use.

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xspace}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\myarrow}{%
s
O{}
m
m
O{1cm}
}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-0.5ex] {
\node[inner sep=0](@1) at (0,0) {#3};
\node[inner sep=0](@2) at (#5,0) {#4};
\IfBooleanTF #1 {
\draw [arrows={-Triangle[open]},shorten >= 2pt,shorten <= 2pt](@1)--(@2) node[pos=.5,above,inner sep=1pt] {#2};}
{\draw [arrows={-Triangle},shorten >= 2pt,shorten <= 2pt](@1)--(@2) node[pos=.5,above,inner sep=1pt] {#2};}}
\end{tikzpicture}\xspace
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Some text \myarrow{$x$}{$y$}, and other text.

White triangle with the starred version: \myarrow*{$x$}{$y$} and other text.

Specify the superscript as optional argument \myarrow*[$i$]{$x$}{$y$}.

Finally you can also set the distance between the two nodes: \myarrow[$i$]{$x$}{$y$}[2cm]

It works also math mode: \[ \myarrow*[$i$]{$x$}{$y$}\]
\end{document}
```

Ti*k*Z draws the content, `xparse` serves to define the new command called `\myarrow` that takes two mandatory arguments (what's on the left and on the right of the arrow respectively). The first optional argument is to typeset something centered above the arrow, while the second optional argument (i.e. after the two set of curly braces) sets the length of the arrow. The starred version `\myarrow*{}{}` provides the white end arrow, which can be drawn invoking the `arrows.meta` library. Finally the package `xspace` is used to deal with the space after the command.

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{mathabx}

\begin{document}
$x \raisebox{3pt}{\underrightarrow{\quad w \quad}} y$
\end{document}
```

[image]